# Tests pass with Playframework 1.2.x but fails with Playframework 1.4.x

Tags: playframework-1.x

I am migrating my application from `Play1.2+Java7` to `Play1.4+Java8`

`Play1.2+Java7` my test passes OK
`Play1.4+Java8` my test fails.

I have reduced the code to the minimum and reproduced the problem. Here is the main line

The model is

```
package models;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Token extends Model {

    public String name;
    public String role;
}
```

The controller is

```
package controllers;

import models.Token;
import play.mvc.Controller;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        renderJSON(Token.all().fetch());
    }

}
```

The DB test configuration is

```
%test.application.mode=dev
%test.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
%test.jpa.ddl=create
```

The test is

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import play.test.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import models.*;

public class ApplicationTest extends FunctionalTest {

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Token.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatIndexPageWorks() {
        {
            Response response = GET("/");
            assertIsOk(response);
            String content = getContent(response);
            System.out.println(content);
            assertFalse(content.contains("le nom"));
            assertFalse(content.contains("identifier"));
        }
        Token t = new Token();
        t.name="le nom";
        t.role="identifier";
        t.save();
        {
            Response response = GET("/");
            assertIsOk(response);
            String content = getContent(response);
            System.out.println(content);
            assertTrue(content.contains("le nom"));
            assertTrue(content.contains("identifier"));
        }
    }

}
```

The behaviour is not predictable. It seems that saving entities in the tests are committed async and calling the controller depends on the threads while it did not in release 1.2

I can provide the whole project if necessary

Answer (score 0):

As I do not want to use the fixtures, I have to manually sync the DB: test call of `model.save()` is done within a local transaction. The transaction is not closed when GET is called. the data is not flushed yet.

I thought that it was covered by 
[jpa FlushModeType COMMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108792/jpa-flushmodetype-commit)

It seems that it is the case in 1.2.x, but not the case in 1.4.x

I modified the test adding the code snippet below after `save()` and  `deleteAll()`, and it works fine

```
    if ( play.db.jpa.JPA.em().getTransaction().isActive()) {
        play.db.jpa.JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
        play.db.jpa.JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
    }
```